# Error: Expected import directive or contract definition

Tags: solidity, solc

Terminal output me this error when I run:

> solc --bin --asm c1.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;

contract Cm {
    uint256 a;

    function Cm() {
        a = 1;
    }
}
```

solc --version --> 0.3.5-371690f0/Debug-Darwin/appleclang/Interpreter

**I solved the problem removing the first line. Is no longer needed to define the solidity version?**

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to have the latest version of `solc`. **[Install documentation](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/installing-solidity.html)**.

Here's how to install on macOS:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew tap ethereum/ethereum
brew install solidity
brew linkapps solidity
```

Run `solc` command to compile and save results to an output directory:

```
solc --bin --asm Example.sol -o build/
```

Generated files:

```
.
├── Example.sol
├── build
│   ├── Example.bin
│   └── Example.evm
```

Version tested with:

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.Darwin.appleclang
```

---

Here are instruction for installing and using `solcjs`:

```
npm install -g solc@latest
```

Call the `solcjs` command with flags and smart contract filename:

```
solcjs --bin --abi Example.sol
```

It'll generate the corresponding files based on the flags you passed:

```
.
├── Example.sol
├── Example_sol_Example.abi
├── Example_sol_Example.bin
```

Version tested with:

```
$ solcjs --version
0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.Emscripten.clang
```

---

Example solidity file used in all examples:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.6;

contract Example {
  function add(uint a, uint b) returns (uint) {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```